# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Performance Issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, performance, xaml, resharper

Lately I'm having lots of trouble with my Visual Studio 2010 IDE. The problem is most noticeable when editing XAML. When I simply change XAML string, scroll up or down, or edit anything at all, IDE lags, does not respond for 20-30 seconds and then recovers and I can work further. Sometimes restarting helps, sometimes it doesn't. This problem makes it really impossible to work normally, but mostly XAML editing is affected. Building and running a small solution (3-4 projects) in debug mode also takes up to 2 minutes.

I have researched this site and Google, with many useful answers, which I mostly tried, but it does not help anything. My own research has come to this:

- Installed addons have no effect, I disabled them all to test
- I want to use InteliSense, so I don't want it disabled (but I tried with it disabled too)
- Hardware/software rendering makes no difference, same with rich client
- Enabling/disabling automatic toolbox generation makes no difference
- Computer is i7 hex-core, 24GB memory and SSD, therefore not a problem (same problem appears on my laptop as well) - Visual Studio doesn't use more than 200MB of memory
- Running latest Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1, with latest version
  of Resharper, also latest Win7 x64
- No conflicting addons with ReSharper

Maybe the problem is SSD ? What else could be the cause of this?

Comment: Do you have Intel RST installed? If so, uninstall it, just to test if that solves your problem. I've had this kind of problems too, and it was Intel RST's fault.

Comment: No, Intel RST is not installed. The motherboard of is ASUS Rampage 3 Extreme, if it helps.

Comment: I have some of the same problems.  But no Resharper.  Rebooting helps (for a while).

Comment: This is very annoying problem. I will probably reformat and try with a new install. Hopefully it will fix the problem.

Comment: You probably don't have enough RAM :)

Comment: For me, it was an extension called "XAML Regions" that slowed the IDE. Disabling it helped a lot. YMMV

Comment: Thank you, but I do not use this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing visual studio again, it helped me. I used to reboot VS, den i cme to rebooting system but once i re installed VS 2010 I m not facing any problems with it.
Hope it helps  :)

Comment: I have just verified this issue on another system, with clean install and it is definitely not the issue. More I am beginning to think it is due to libraries used by project, because I the studio was much faster with another project (however still not fast enough) and especially it gets laggy with XAML user controls that project has.